# Does the size of code F aircraft parking apron enough for 2 code C plane?

Tags: airport, airport-design

When I look at Inner Thames Estuary Airport (Isle of Grain) [masterplan](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/isle-of-grain-master-plan.pdf), they shows a funny figure about the terminals layout.
[image]

The report describes that  ***It shows the ability for most
stands to handle either a large wide bodied (Code E/F) aircraft or two narrow bodied (Code C) aircraft.***

The question is, is it true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of parking system is called MARS (Multi Aircraft (or Apron) Ramp System) and is being used or explored by many airports.

You can see markings for them on the ground at CLE.  Here is a google maps link to one of the stand areas.  [CLE terminal](https://www.google.com/maps/place/41%C2%B024'42.4%22N+81%C2%B050'27.5%22W/@41.411785,-81.840977,232m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)

[Here](http://www.airportsinternational.com/2013/02/manoeuvres-on-mars/13873) is an article on the stands.